# Вставить очень много INSERT за один раз из строк в файле

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт сбрасывает в текстовый файл либо строки, либо готовые выражения, потом *скрипт-вставлятор-в-бд* парсит файл и либо берет команды оттуда, либо на основе текстовых строк генерирует insert.

Как правильно оформить множественные insert-ы в базу, чтобы получилось максимально быстро? Файлы могут быть до ~5 мб, поэтому нагрузка довольно неплохая будет.

Какие опции при insert нужно включить и как правильно сформировать запрос? В одной вставке, например можно сразу несколько записей сделать типа *INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);*, на каково максимальное/оптимальное количество?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Максимальное количество записей зависит от длины запроса. Оно задается переменной `max_allowed_packet`.

Узнать значение этой (или другой) переменной можно выполнив один из нижеприведенных запросов:

```
SELECT @@max_allowed_packet;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_allowed_packet";
```

Насчет замены на "кучу insert" проверил - плохая идея. Сделал скрипт, который грузит 10000 строк случайных данных в три поля InnoDB-таблицы (integer, varchar(32), varchar(40)). Второе поле - индекс. Замерял время для четырех вариантов:

1. Для каждой строки свой `INSERT`, выполняющийся через `mysqli_query()`;
2. Запрос подготавливается `mysqli_prepare()`, потом для каждой строки подставляются значения и выполняется подготовленный запрос;
3. Формируется многострочный `INSERT` и выполняется через `mysqli_query()`;
4. Сформированный CSV-файл грузится в таблицу через `LOAD INFILE...`.

Результаты примерно такие:

1. 14 сек;
2. 11 сек;
3. 0,5 сек;
4. 0,3 сек.

PHP 5.4.45, MySQL 5.5.46

Comment: Ну вот max_allowed_packet он же в мегабайтах измеряется. Получается мне нужно программно составлять строку, пока она будет меньше нужного размера? ( Как, кстати, из php с помощью mysqli узнать max_allowed_packet?). А не быстрее ли в таком случае будет просто кучу insert сделать?

Comment: @Ипатьев Век живи - век учись - дураком помрешь. Спасибо, Сенсей! Только соотношение результатов 1-2 и 3-4 не поменялось и 1,2 явно дольше, чем 3,4

Comment: Спасибо за анализ и подробное представление. В общем пока, наверное на load data остановимся, действительно.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин Если он не доступен, то многострочный INSERT вполне неплохой вариант

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, я не работаю не с MySQL не с PHP, но знаю, что для ситуации, как Ваша, все базы данных имеют издревле так называемую **Bulk Copy** возможность. Это, например, [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188365.aspx) в Microsoft SQL Server'е.

Поэтому поискав немного, я нашел кое-что, что может быть Вам полезно. Взгляните на [эту статью](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/), где сравниваются несколько вариантов, включая [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). Поискав еще, можно найти [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26250247/315935), [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20877176/315935) [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15363068/315935) и много других примеров использования `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Мне кажется, это то, что Вы ищите.

Comment: Да, только вот Also, to use LOAD DATA INFILE on server files, you must have the FILE privilege. Только таких привилегий не всегда есть. То есть мне нужно чисто используля mysqli это сделать.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин: если для вас нужна скорость, то это **единственная возможность**, известная мне. Можно написать Windows сервис запускаемый под account'ом у которого есть соответствующие права и из другой программы общаться с этим сервисом.

Comment: Я понял. Хорошо, оставлю это как запасной вариант. Спасибо за линки!

Comment: @АлександрПушкин: Пожалуйста! Будут вопросы - попробую помочь.